# Moving widgets on fly using GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, gwt

I have just started working with GWT. I was wondering how I can dynamically move widgets on fly (at web page on client browser) for example to move a row of table up and down, or upload a excel file and display its content right away....something like a dashboard I am talking about. Are there any comprehensive tutorial to refer.

Comment: Check out the apache POI features for readin n writing xls files..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the gwt-dnd lib:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see it is for mobile devices, i was wondering will it work over websites as well?

Answer (score 0):

GWT is made for doing the kind of things you are describing.  To move widgets you can either set their position or dynamically modify their css.  To move rows around in a table look at the api of whatever table class you are using.  To upload an excel file do a google search for 'gwt upload' and there will be some instructions - but to display the file you will need to convert it (probably to xml).  Converting the file on the server will depend on which server you are using - I also have seen a 3rd party widget that will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If youre looking for transition effects or animations , than check out gwtquery. Its really similar to jquery and has pretty simple good examples to start with.

Comment: @Shukly Kappon: thanks, this would be helpful in development :)